# Where is the POST message body in the Firefox Network Tools Utility

Tags: http, firefox, post

I'm trying to debug a web app and need to look at a series of requests/responses. I'm using the Firefox Developer's tools Network tool which shows the traffic and details but I'm not able to find the POST request body.  Where is it?  A screen shot of a Google request that includes POST operations is shown below.

[image]

Comment: you are in Headers tab, and you need to move to the right tabs (cookies), Params, **Response**

Comment: The response has the response body content.  I need the request body content.

Comment: And you have taken a look at the "Params" tabs?